# How to avoid or delete TFS plugin configuration in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, tfs, tfvc

Currently whenever I create a project it's appearing the following message 3 times

[image]

Is there a way to avoid it or delete previously configuration from TFS plugin?

Because whenever I want to "Get Latest Version" (download files from TFS) comes out this window

[image]